# How to append into txt file through karate.write(value,file.txt) function?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, karate

karate.write(value, file.txt) overwrite the previous content whenever called.

I want to append values every time i call to karate.write function.

In my code i need to call this function 10 times at different points. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I already saw that post what you suggest @peter. I just want to know that how can i get rid of overwrite issue if i call write function in my 10 different scenario of one feature file.

Comment: by writing a custom Java class to do the exact work you need. otherwise you can't do this